# XSLT extraction of all input possible xpaths

Tags: java, xml, api, xslt

I have really complex xsl (20 000 rows xsl file!) file which processes input file XML and makes output XML file.
I would like to extract all input file xpaths which are possible processed in the xsl. So I would like somehow to have a extraction of all (input)xpaths which are concerned in the XSL.
For that purpose I would like to find java API or tool which is  able to give me this information with single passing of the XSL file. Are there such APIs or tools?

Regards
Aurel

Comment: The answer is negative. And I believe that the only such "tool" is an XSLT debugger. One cannot produce dhe XPath expressions for dynamically created nodes or for nodes referenced by a variable.

Comment: XSLT is Turing Complete, so you basically end up with the halting problem.

Comment: Bearing those restrictions in mind, you can at least get all the *static* XPaths from all the 'select' attributes.

Comment: Err, oops, the 'select' and 'match' attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, that's easy- every node's processed in some way. I'm guessing what you really want is "what's specifically processed by a template that's defined in the stylesheet."

To do that, just add the identity template to the very bottom of your stylesheet- anything which hasn't already been processed already will be processed by that, and you can add in an `<xsl:message>` instruction to output whatever you need there. I'm fairly sure you'll find examples of how to generate the XPath of the context node around, that's been asked a few times.

EDIT: I forgot to mention- technically this will give you the inverse of what you asked for, it'll tell you what nodes are NOT processed. Hopefully you'll be able to use that to achieve the same goal though.

Comment: Thank you, but the purpose of my question is to build correct input file...I don't have any input file...That's why I cannot trace any information. I have just xsl and I want to know what are all possible input file xpaths which are concerned in the xsl. With this information I will build proper input file. Any other ideas ?

Comment: Ah.. well, if you do find a means of doing it, you can possibly use this technique to check the input file once it's built.